# What's the easiest way to maintain a patched set of rails gems, with bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

We're transitioning from 'frozen' rails gems to using bundler and would like to maintain the rails gems with patches, merges etc. say from an external git source.  What's the easiest way to set this up, adding gemspecs to the patch branches etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I would store them on a place accessible to bundler (like a public repo on github), in your gemfile use the `:git=>` option like

```
gem "nokogiri", :git =>
  "git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git"
```

Comment: Yes, but bundler wants gems not repos.  The rails gems specifically do not have gemspecs--so the question is what's the easiest way to get bundler to install these from git as you suggest?  The question was not how to install nokogiri with bundler nor any other gem that already has a gemspec in the repo.  How to create a gemspec for the rails gems then might be a good part of the answer I'm looking for.